# Blacklist [subjective]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist

I thought [subjective](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) was blacklisted already, but it made its way onto [a recent question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/159183/1).

It's one of the [unholy trinity of bad meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/): can it be blacklisted here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blacklisted.

[image]